# java openx api v1 or v2

Tags: api, openx

using openX api which api is better way v1 or v2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read that v1 is deprecated. Also v2 has some API calls (related to trackers) which does not exists in v1. v2 seems the obvious solution for me.

Comment: can you tell me any link where it is written that v1 is depreciated ?
please also tell me that v2 having dependency over groovy is there any java native calls for v2 ?

Comment: http://developer.openx.org/wiki/display/API/Home. "As of OpenX 2.7, the API v1 is deprecated. The API v2 uses a single XML-RPC endpoint and allows the API to be extended using plugins"

Comment: can i use api v2 with native java code i don't want to make groovy calls

Comment: I answered on the other question - yes you can.

Comment: thanks very much for the response, can you give me any tutorial url using api v2 with java-xml rpc client library.

Comment: There is no tutorial from what I know. If you have specific question I can answer to them.

Comment: Oh yes now i know we need to call api v2 methods with ox.login for example and library will remain same as we use for v1, i am gr8full to you, you solved my biggest problem.